# When creating dynamic div elements in a loop and attaching event handlers, event is fired for last element only

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create dynamic div elements and adding click events on these div element. I'm creating them by for loop. But event handler is working for only last element created by for loop. Below is my full code.

```js
function givealert(count) {
  if (count != 0) {
    createDiv();
  }
}

function createDiv(numberOfDiv) {
  var navitemlabels = ['Home', 'Products', 'Services', 'About'];
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < navitemlabels.length; i++) {
    var newitem = document.createElement('div');
    var itemid = "div" + i;
    newitem.id = "div" + i;
    newitem.className = "navdivs square";
    newitem.innerHTML = navitemlabels[i];
    newitem.addEventListener("click", function() {

      if (newitem.classList.contains('selected') || newitem.classList.contains('square')) {
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("selected");
        //alert(x[0])
        if (x.length == 0) {
          toggleColor(newitem);
        } else if (newitem == x[0]) {
          toggleColor(newitem);
        } else {
          toggleColor(newitem, x[0]);
        }
      }
    })
    document.getElementById("navbar").appendChild(newitem);
  }
}

function toggleColor(selecteddiv, lastSelected) {
  if (!lastSelected) {
    selecteddiv.classList.toggle("square");
    selecteddiv.classList.toggle("selected");
  } else {
    selecteddiv.classList.toggle("square");
    selecteddiv.classList.toggle("selected");
    lastSelected.classList.toggle("square");
    lastSelected.classList.toggle("selected");
  }

}
```

```css
.selected {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.square:hover {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.navdivs {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.square {
  background-color: rgb(69, 205, 233);
}
```

```html
<body onload="givealert(4)">
  <div id="navbar"></div>
</body>
```

When I'm running this file, 4 div elements are getting created but only last element has working click event function. When clicked, last elements stays as clicked but for other div elements that is not happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The series of if elses you had seemed very complex for a simple toggle. Below i modified your addEventListener to simply call toggleColor. Once in toggle color you know this = element that was clicked. after that you can use querySelector to grab the selected element and toggle its classes.

```js
function givealert(count){
    if(count != 0){
        createDiv();
    }
}

function createDiv(numberOfDiv){ 
    var navitemlabels = ['Home', 'Products', 'Services', 'About'];
    var i;
    for(i=0; i<navitemlabels.length; i++)
    {
        var newitem = document.createElement('div');
        var itemid = "div"+i;
        newitem.id = "div"+i;
        newitem.className = "navdivs square";
        newitem.innerHTML = navitemlabels[i];    
        newitem.addEventListener("click", toggleColor);
        document.getElementById("navbar").appendChild(newitem);
    }   
}

function toggleColor() {
  const selected = document.querySelector('.selected');
    if (selected) {
      selected.classList.toggle("square");
      selected.classList.toggle("selected");
    }
    this.classList.toggle("square");
    this.classList.toggle("selected");
  
  }
```

```css
.selected{
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  }
  
  .square:hover {
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  }
  
  .navdivs{
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
    display:inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .square{
       background-color: rgb(69, 205, 233);
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="navbar.css">
</head>
<body onload="givealert(4)">
    <div id="navbar"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `this` instead of `newitem` in your click handler

```js
function givealert(count) {
  if (count != 0) {
    createDiv();
  }
}

function createDiv(numberOfDiv) {
  var navitemlabels = ['Home', 'Products', 'Services', 'About'];
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < navitemlabels.length; i++) {
    var newitem = document.createElement('div');
    var itemid = "div" + i;
    newitem.id = "div" + i;
    newitem.className = "navdivs square";
    newitem.innerHTML = navitemlabels[i];
    newitem.addEventListener("click", function(e) {

      if (this.classList.contains('selected') || this.classList.contains('square')) {
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("selected");
        //alert(x[0])
        if (x.length == 0) {
          toggleColor(this);
        } else if (this == x[0]) {
          toggleColor(this);
        } else {
          toggleColor(this, x[0]);
        }
      }
    })
    document.getElementById("navbar").appendChild(newitem);
  }
}

function toggleColor(selecteddiv, lastSelected) {
  if (!lastSelected) {
    selecteddiv.classList.toggle("square");
    selecteddiv.classList.toggle("selected");
  } else {
    selecteddiv.classList.toggle("square");
    selecteddiv.classList.toggle("selected");
    lastSelected.classList.toggle("square");
    lastSelected.classList.toggle("selected");
  }

}
```

```css
.selected {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.square:hover {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.navdivs {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.square {
  background-color: rgb(69, 205, 233);
}
```

```html
<body onload="givealert(4)">
  <div id="navbar"></div>
</body>
```